# Is there a way to do multi-part uploads to my S3 bucket on an android app without using the AWS SDK for android?

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This might seem strange at first considering the easiest way is to work with the SDK, but it's not an option for me. The reason being, I'm actually building a Third Party API and allowing for the upload of files to my bucket.

The first person consuming my API is an android application and I'd like to get some idea as to the best way to make this possible.

I can't give 3rd party developers my AWS credentials.

I've authorised this on my website with Cross Origin Resource Sharing and signed requests. Is there a similar way to do this on android?

Ideally I'd like the flow to be:

1. 3rd party app sends me the file info, key, etc.
2. my API service signs the request and sends it back.
3. The app then uses the request to upload the file.

Is this possible on Android?

I've read up on STS and creating temporary credentials, but that's still not nailing down permissions to a per-request level like the signed request method allows me to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Browser based Form Upload feature offered by AWS for S3. Even though use case is described as browser upload, but it can be easily used by any http client.

1. Third Party Client (Android etc) calls your server to create a upload policy
2. Your server creates a signed policy by making AWS S3 API Call (YOu may use SDK to do that). This policy may allow upload for a particular key in S3.
3. The Android Client can submit the multi-part data using S3 key, signed policy.

   Here is an example for HTML Form (You can easily use any http client to do for Android App) :
   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HTTPPOSTExamples.html

This approach will only require your to share IAM Access key but not secret key.

Another alternative is to totally abstract S3 and let your server manage the upload: